# How to maintain object repository for selenium instead of writing it again and again?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am doing an automation where i am writing xpath for some elements again and again how to maintain a centralized repository to access from java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to create a common Object Repository for locators.For Eg:

1. Read from the excel sheet and at the beginning of execution get all locators into hashmap.
2. Create a class and keep locators as class level variables.
3. Read from properties file like a key value pair.

This totally depends upon you framework .

Answer (score 2):

Use PAGE OBJECT MODEL.

See this for reference: [CLICK](https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html)

Quoting from link above, here is one of its benefits:

> The Second benefit is the object repository is independent of test cases, so we can use the same object repository for a different purpose with different tools. For example, we can integrate POM with TestNG/JUnit for functional Testing and at the same time with JBehave/Cucumber for acceptance testing.